# Separate values from date datatype using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to separate values from date datatype

### Data

```
time                            ID  
2021-04-16T00:00:00.000-0800    AA
2021-04-23T00:00:00.000-0800    AA
2021-04-30T00:00:00.000-0800    BB
```

### Desired

```
time        ID  
2021-04-16  AA
2021-04-23  AA
2021-04-30  BB
```

### Doing

```
df["time"] = df["time"].str.extract(r'(\w+)')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.date
```

As @Umar.H suggests -- thank you! --, one can use `dt.normalize`, instead of `dt.date`, to leave the column `time` as `datetime64`:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.normalize()
```

Output:

```
         time  ID
0  2021-04-16  AA
1  2021-04-23  AA
2  2021-04-30  BB
```

Comment: `dt.normalize` to keep it a datetime object. you could put it into a single step as well instead of two lines

Comment: ok this works - will vote up in 9 min - thank you

Comment: Thanks, @Umar.H, for having commented my answer! I have learned something important from you: I had never heard about `dt.normalize`! Thanks! I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: yup, it places the time to `00:00:00` essentially printing it as a date, but leaving it as a datetime object which is super useful when it comes to working with datetime objects :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is that, you could split the time column at the 'T' character and select the first element.

```py
df['time'] = df['time'].str.split('T').str[0]
```

Output:

```
  time        ID
0 2021-04-16  AA
1 2021-04-23  AA
2 2021-04-30  BB
```